# Bouncing turtle functions but doesn't run

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a code for school where a turtle bounces around in a square. So far it's not visible, which I plan to change. The problem is when I run the code, nothing happens, and I can't figure out why. Any help is welcome. the xxturt and yyturt is an attempt at setting back the turtle in case it passes the borders

```
import turtle
import random
turt=turtle.Turtle()


while True:
  xturt = turt.xcor()
  yturt = turt.ycor()
  if abs(xturt) >= 50:
    heading = turt.heading()
    for i in range(1):
      rand=random.randint(90,150)
      xxturt=xturt-50
    turt.back(xxturt)
    turt.setheading(rand + heading)
    turt.fd(1)

  if abs(yturt) >= 50:
heading = turt.heading()
    for i in range(1):
      rando=random.randint(90,150)
      yyturt=yturt-50
    turt.back(yyturt)
    turt.setheading(rando + heading)
    turt.fd(1)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Add some print statements or use python's logging facility at various points in your code to see where it gets stuck and what is happening at that time.

Comment: "So far it's not visible, which I plan to change" I suggest you fix this first. It is much easier to understand what your code is doing if you can see the results.

Answer (score 1):

> Bouncing turtle functions but doesn't run

So the turtle "doesn't run", is "not visible" and "nothing happens" but it "functions"?  Really?

Fixing the incorrectly indented line that keeps the code from even starting, the reason it doesn't do anything is that you wrote code for when it "passes the borders" but didn't write *anything* for it to do otherwise.  It can't wander beyond its borders if it's not moving at all.

Let's simplify your code and see if we can't get the turtle to basically move:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle('turtle')

while True:
    x, y = turtle.position()

    if not abs(x) < 100 > abs(y):
        turtle.backward(1)

        heading = turtle.heading()
        rand = 180 + randint(-30, 30)

        turtle.setheading(rand + heading)

    turtle.forward(1)

screen.exitonclick()  # never reached
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry when I said "isnt visible", I was referring to the box the turtle is trapped in. Thanks for explaining everything to me.